# What do you call an implemented Enum type?

Tags: java, enums, terminology

As part of my Bachelor Thesis, I implemented an Enum type (with the constants and some methods) for the project I am working on. However, I am unsure how to call it in the thesis itself. I started with "Enum-class", but since it is missing the `class` keyword, I don't know whether I could really call it a class. "Enum-type" sounds a bit weird, since enum is already a data type, and I want to refer to my implementation and not the general Java type. Is there a convention how to refer to Enums?

Comment: Just `enum` as this seems to be consistent to me. We call a class `class`, an interface `interface`, and an enum `enum`. You could append `implementation` like `class implementation`, `interface implementation`, and `enum implementation`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use enumeration, since that what is is. Compare the dictionary entry for enumeration

> enumerate: mention (a number of things) one by one

versus the definition for enum types from the Java tuturial

> An enum type is a type whose fields consist of a fixed set of constants

So for example for an enumeration of all the weekdays, it would use the weekdays-enum(eration). No need to invent a new term for it

Comment: I agree... the problem is that there's a `java.util.Enumeration`

Comment: There is also a `java.lang.Class` which does not stop us from referring to a class with the word class. Similar for methods, fields, ... .

Answer (score 1):

You can simply call it "enum", e.g. "the Colors enum", "the Seasons enum", etc.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of completeness; I just stumbled across Oracles Java tutorial about enumerations. It says:

> The `enum` declaration defines a *class* (called an *enum type*).

(Source: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html)

I currently use enumeration (as Robin suggested) or enumeration-type in my thesis.